# What is the path to my external executable that I've included?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, relative-path

So I was successfully able to run a command line application with various arguments from within my project using the following code:

```
String f = fileName;
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\projects\\something\\MediaInfo.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " \"--Inform=Video;%Duration%|%Width%|%Height%;\" \"" + f + "\"";
process.Start();
StreamReader output = process.StandardOutput;
process.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(output.ReadToEnd());
```

Now, rather than the absolute path I've specified for MediaInfo.exe I'd like to specify a relative path so that when I send my application to someone they won't need to muck about with placing it in the correct place.

In Visual Studio, I select my project and clicked add existing. I added my files. Then selected "Always Copy." I've tried various items for the "Build Action." I have a feeling "None" is the correct option.

In any case, my goal is to have `process.StartInfo.FileName` be a relative path. I don't know how to do this right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root directory of your application can be obtained by...

```
string appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

This statement requires System.IO and System.Diagnostics in order to compile.

You can append to this value to reach a subdirectory, for example "data", in your application root by...

```
string dataPath = Path.Combine(appRoot, "data");
```

The application needs to be running in full trust for these to work...

Comment: Ahhh that isn't the right path. That gives me some path to my application directory. I can see the files being copied to my debug folder or release folder; so I know they are getting copied somewhere. This path isn't that one though. Close!

Comment: Ahh found it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction: String appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

Answer (score 0):

Change "C:\projects\something\MediaInfo.exe" to "MediaInfo.exe", so your app will try to find it at the same directory. Make sure release your app with "MediaInfo.exe", that's all.

The "Always Copy" stuff only copies "MediaInfo.exe" to output directory, it doesn't help if you hard code the file path.